# Question about Relative Cohomology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I need help with the following question please:

Suppose that a space $X \subseteq Y $ retracts onto some subspace $A \subseteq X $.

> When do I have $H^\ast ( Y,X) \cong H^\ast  (Y,A)$?

Thanks.

Comment: Deleted a mistaken comment of mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is false in general. Let $Y$ be a disk, $X$ be its boundary and $A$ be a point on the boundary. Then $H^2(Y, X) \cong \Bbb Z$ whereas $H^2(Y, A)$ is trivial.

Now if you mean $X$ *deformation* retracts onto $A$, then the statement is true. In this case, use the long exact sequence of the triple $(Y, X, A)$ and note that the inclusion $A \hookrightarrow X$ induces an isomorphism.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification... If you could please help with the specific case where $ A= \left\lbrace (x,-x) \mid x \in S^n \right\rbrace $,$ X= S^n \times S^n \setminus \Delta $ and $Y= S^n \times S^n$ ($\Delta $ is the diagonal) . Does $X$ deformation retract onto $A$?

Comment: @KerryH This looks familiar. What's the context of the question? Also, it's better to start a new question than to re-purpose an existing question. Now the beginning of my answer doesn't make sense.

Comment: Oh... sorry... I just thought I should fix it because I said "prove" for something that's wrong to begin with!

Comment: @KerryH No worries.